# How to forward using run a script?

Tags: vba, outlook

I receive mails, from two senders, with two subjects, to a specific address.

I set up a rule:

> ```
> from:   example@example.com or example2@example2.com  
> sent to:  me@me.com  
> and with:  Company return doc or Daily document Country in the subject  
> except if the subject contains "FW:"
> ```

to run a script:

```
Sub myRuleMacro(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim selEmail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set selEmail = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1).Forward
    selEmail.Recipients.Add "address@address.pl"
    selEmail.Send
    Set selEmail = Nothing
End Sub
```

The script works for the selected email but to select it I need to click it manually, or if any other email is already clicked/marked it forwards this marked email, not the one from the rule.

How to choose the mail from the rule to trigger the macro?

Basically I need the solution which will forward the email. I cannot use the forwarding rule due to company safety policies.

Comment: Are you trying to forward the email or just the body of the email?

Comment: I am trying to forward original message, with an original attachment, with an original body, to a new list of recipients

Comment: Yes, it did. It is running smoothly as it was supposed to. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You all most got it, it should be*

*Example*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub myRuleMacro(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim selEmail As Outlook.MailItem

    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        Set selEmail = Item.Forward
            selEmail.Subject = Item.Subject
            selEmail.HTMLBody = Item.HTMLBody
            selEmail.Recipients.Add "address@address.pl"

            selEmail.Save
            selEmail.Send
    End If
End Sub
```

*No need for `Selection.Item` and make sure to `save` it before sending it*

Comment: it is working like a charm. Thank you very much for the support.

Answer (score 0):

The email that the rule is triggered on is already being passed to the sub `Item as Outlook.MailItem` -- `Sub myRuleMacro(**Item As Outlook.MailItem**)`

You're not using this provided item and selecting a DIFFERENT item when you use `Set selEmail = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1).Forward`

You should be able to simply use Item.Forward

Try

```
Sub myRuleMacro(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
   Dim newForward as MailItem
   Set newForward = Item.Forward
   newForward.Recipients.Add "address@address.pl"
   newForward.Send
End Sub
```

EDITED: To include updates by @Tony Dallimore in comments.

Comment: While trying your code I get:

Run-time error '424':

Object required

Comment: Add `Dim newForward as MailItem` and change `newForward = Item.Forward` to `Set newForward = Item.Forward`

Comment: You are not clearing Recipients before added the new address so the forwarded email will go to all the original recipients.  Is this what you want?

Comment: Firstly thank you very much for support. Secondly, I would like to send the forwarded message to the new recipients, without original recipients. So clearing recipients before added the new address would be a must, haven't thought about that, neither do I have a clue how to do that :(

Comment: @PawełKędzielski  `Recipients` is a type of `Collection` which has methods such as `Add` and `Remove`.  `Do While newForward.Recipients.Count > 0`  `newForward.Recipients.Remove 1` `Loop` would remove recipients one by one until none were left.  However, this is unnecessary.  I had not known that `Forward` clears `Recipients` for you.  So this was a useful lesson for me.